# Calculating Date Difference in Google Sheet Script Editor

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to calculate today() - past date in script editor

I have all these dates already in the raw data

They are in the below format..

10/31/2018
10/31/2018
11/8/2018
11/11/2018
11/18/2018
11/18/2018

I tried these codes for calculation

```
function getDate(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Lists')
  var data = sh.getRange('A:A').getValues(); // read all data in the sheet
  var sec=1000;
  var min=60*sec;
  var hour=60*min;
  var day=24*hour;
  var hd=new Date(data).valueOf();
  var td=new Date().valueOf();
  var diff=td-hd;
  var days=Math.floor(diff/day);
 // range.offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows, numColumns)


  Logger.log('Day_Difference:',days);
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length(),2).setValues(days); // write back to the sheet

}
```

but I get an error message saying,

```
TypeError: Cannot call property length in object Dates,Wed Oct 31 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT),Wed Oct 31 2018
```

Should I do different formats for these calculation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can convert dates to timestamp epochs in milliseconds to make this easier.

Usually when doing a lot of work with dates folks use the `moment` library which can be found here: https://github.com/moment/moment. However if this is a simple scenario and a bulk of code is not to be written around dates would just do a simple script.

```js
const dates = [
  '10/31/2018', 
  '10/31/2018', 
  '11/8/2018', 
  '11/11/2018', 
  '11/18/2018', 
  '11/18/2018'
];

function dateDifference(a, b) {
  const aEpoch = +new Date(a);
  const bEpoch = +new Date(b);
  
  const maxEpoch = Math.max(aEpoch, bEpoch);
  const minEpoch = Math.min(aEpoch, bEpoch);
  
  return maxEpoch - minEpoch;
}

console.log(dateDifference(dates[0], dates[1])); // Expect 0
console.log(dateDifference(dates[1], dates[2])); // Expect 694800000 milliseconds
```

Comment: Hey Joshua, I tried these codes, and I `m also trying to append these values into my google sheet (Column B) - basically scan Column A (original dates) and then insert the calculated dates into column B. but when I use setValues method, (setValues(diff)), it gives me error, "Cannot find method setValues(number). (line 17, file "sddsds")". Should we use different method for this?

Comment: If says cannot find method this means that method, or function defined on that object, is not available. So in this code, means sh.getRange is not returning what you think it is. Would log the output and see what is being returned and go for there